# Hangfire Job: Fires and does not execute and still status is successful

Tags: hangfire

There is a particular job that I use my Hangfire to execute and it does not execute and it returns success, it does not show any exception it just moves straight to successful, what could be the issue:

Below is the function signature:

```
ResultsHelper.ImportTermScores(
    "C:\HostingSpaces\wwwroot\uploads\JSS 1 J 1st.xlsx",
    5,
    1,
    "2014JSS1J",
    52,
    "Admin");
```